# Symfony Cache Validation error: Cannot declare class Response after using setPublic()

Tags: php, symfony, http-caching

I'm playing with [HTTP Cache Validation - Validation with the ETag Header](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/validation.html#validation-with-the-etag-header)

In my controller I have:

```
// ... get the $data and $myObject somehow ...

$response = $this->json($data);
$response->setEtag($myObject->getDateModified()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));  // getDateModified() returns a DateTime
$response->setPublic();

return $response;
```

The first time the page is loaded after deleting the cache, the controller is run and everything is fine. But starting from the second time I just get:

> FatalErrorException in classes.php line 3353: Error: Cannot declare
>   class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, because the name is
>   already in use

this probleme is there as soon as I use `$response->setPublic();`

What is causing the problem? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I can't figure out what is causing the error.
My error is `Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag in /...var/cache/prod/classes.php`.
The problem is gone when I comment out `$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);` inside `app.php`, but that is not a solution :/

Comment: No it is not but you made me feel less alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, maybe it could help you https://github.com/contao/core-bundle/issues/643

They suggest removing the line `$kernel->loadClassCache();` from `app.php`.

> It is a speedup attempt which preloads classes which are needed in
>   most requests. This is however obsolete in PHP7.0 and marginal in PHP
>   5.6 - therefore it is save to remove it.

EDIT: I removed line `$kernel->loadClassCache();` and there is no more errors and http cache is working normally.

Also, here is extra info: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20668

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Instead, it changes the error to:  ``ContextErrorException in RequestDataCollector.php line 128:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0``

Comment: What Symfony version do you have?

Comment: symfony 3.2.0  on php 7.0.9

Comment: In version 3.2.0, line 128. in RequestDataCollector is `$value = array_map(function ($v) { return isset($v[1]) ? $v : $v[0]; }, $value);`

but, there was problem with null header values, so in version 3.2.1 it was fixed - `$value = array_map(function ($v) { return isset($v[0]) && !isset($v[1]) ? $v[0] : $v; }, $value);`

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/adc4a26971749d31d23f8a5f2ec80243231cb421

Comment: Thank you Matko! It is working after comment $kernel->loadClassCache();. You save my day.

Comment: This answer should definitely be accepted @ShinDarth. It solves your issue. You just also have another issue.